# problem to understand how to use jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

i'm tried to understand the jquery tabs plugin of ui but i don't get it. i also follow the example in the docs but i don't make to run see my code and tell me why am i doing wrong Because i don' see it .

**html code**

```
<div class="header">
        <div class="headerContainer">
          <div class="logoContainer"></div>
          <div id="menuContainer" class="tab">
            <ul id="menuPrincipal">
                <li>
                <a href="#tabs-1">Quienes Somos</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="#tabs-2">Catalogo de Repuestos</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="#tabs-3">Cotizacion OnLine</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="#tabs-4">Catalogo de Repuestos</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div id="tab-1">
        Contenido para internet
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2">
        Contenido para tecnologías WAP
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3">
        Contenido para plugins jQuery
    </div>
    <div id="tab-4">
        Contenido de prueba
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

function initialize(){

    $( "#menuContainer" ).tabs();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Issues, place the content `div`s in the same parent `div` as your `ul`.

2nd, your links are to `#tabs-...` but your divs have ids that are `tab-...`, no s.

http://jsfiddle.net/FFPVy/

Comment: hi and thanks for asking one question if i put styles to my divs could be a cause to stop to work the plugin?? because i tried and don't work and the only difference that i see it's the css file

Comment: I do believe the css is important with tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Your links are linking to the plural`#tabs-3`, while your div is actually called the singular `#tab-3`.

Comment: hi and thanks for asking one question if i put styles to my divs could be a cause to stop to work the plugin?? because i tried and don't work and the only difference that i see it's the css file